# Can exponentiation be seen as a group morphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exponentiation

In this video by "Three Blue One Brown" dealing with group theory  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvmuCPvRoWQ

the operation of exponentiation is presented as a group morphism, that is a structure preserving function from an additive group to a multplicative group.

the quick justification provided at ***16:52*** is the exponent law $n^{a+b} = n^a\times n^b$. I think the author only takes this law as an example of a more general " exponential property" that shows up regularly in group theory.

Is there a not too complicated way to make this idea more precise?

Comment: The function $e^x$ is a group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ to $(\mathbb{R}^+, \cdot)$. In fact, it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The homomorphism property is $h(x+y)=h(x)+h(y)$.  The exponential map $h:(\Bbb R,+)\to(\Bbb R^+,\cdot)$, given by $h(x)=e^x$, indeed satisfies this property.  We have $h(x+y)=e^{x+y}=e^x\cdot e^y=h(x)\cdot h(y)$.

Comment: That perfectly answers my question, thanks.